# Plotly Dash drag graph to dynamically reposition plot

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

My user wants to be able to drag graphs etc and re-position them on the app layout.
I've had no luck with my google searches - any books, or other pointers would be very welcome.
I'm looking for something like Apache NiFi.

Comment: I've found this [link](http://mzabriskie.github.io/react-draggable/example/) for react which should help me a lot.

Comment: Good to see that you got a solution! In the future, please consider whether something is relevant for future readers. If so, please post an answer to your own question. If not, consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from the asker, the question was resolved by using React Draggable:

http://mzabriskie.github.io/react-draggable/example/